# Show that $T : C([-1,1],\mathbb{R}) \to C([-1,1],\mathbb{R})$ is a contraction

Tags: metric-spaces, contraction-operator

I am trying to show that $T : C([-1,1],\mathbb{R}) \to C([-1,1],\mathbb{R})$ is a contraction, where $T$ is defined by
$$T(f)(x) = \pi x + \int\limits_{-1}^1\frac{f(t)dt}{\pi+(x-t)^4}.$$
I am not having much luck in my attempts so far.

Comment: What norm are you using?

Comment: @zim I am using $|| ||_\infty$

Comment: I believe that it would suffice if $\int_{-1}^1|\frac{1}{\pi+(x-t)^4}|dt\in\left]0,1\right[$ were true...

Answer (score 2):

Note that $f$ is affine; we can write $T(f)$ as the sum of a fixed function (independent of $f$) $\pi x$, plus a linear map:
$$S : C([0, 1], \Bbb{R}) \to C([0, 1], \Bbb{R}) : f \mapsto \int_{-1}^1 \frac{f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t}{\pi + (x - t)^4}.$$
It's easy to see that $T$ is a contraction if and only if $S$ is a contraction. Using the linearity of $S$, we simply need to show that $\|S(f)\|_\infty < 1$ whenever $\|f\|_\infty \le 1$.

Suppose $\|f\|_\infty \le 1$. Then $|f(x)| \le 1$ for all $x \in [-1, 1]$. Consequently, if $x \in [-1, 1]$,
\begin{align*}
|S(f)(x)| &= \left|\int_{-1}^1 \frac{f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t}{\pi + (x - t)^4}\right| \\
&\le \int_{-1}^1 \frac{|f(t)| \, \mathrm{d}t}{\pi + (x - t)^4} \\
&\le \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\pi} = \frac{2}{\pi}.
\end{align*}
Hence $\|S(f)\|_\infty \le 2/\pi < 1$. That is, $S$ (and hence $T$) is a contraction. Not only that, $S$ and $T$ are Banach contractions, meaning that there is some $k \in [0, 1)$ such that
$$\|T(f_1) - T(f_2)\|_\infty \le k\|f_1 - f_2\|_\infty.$$
This is useful if you wish to apply the Banach Fixed Point Theorem to $T$ (applying it to $S$ would be boring, as $0$ is a fixed point of any linear map!).

Comment: Thank you @user804886, in fact I needed this result to use the Fixed Point Theorem.

Comment: @TroyW. I had an inkling... ;-)